# How to know web application URL in Servlet application

Tags: java, servlets

I want to be able to access, statically (or globally somehow) the URL of my own application, that is, I want to know the URL of the root context path, so for instance if it is in:

http://example.com/contextroot/

I want to be able to get this information in any part of my app. So I guess I have to obtain this information after the application is initialized, my instincts tells me it is somewhere among listeners or Servlet interceptors, but I'm not sure where can I store this information in, for example, a Singleton.

Comment: do you mean like using `@RequestMapping(value="/contextroot", method = RequestMethod.GET)`?

Comment: @HassanAlBourji I never mentioned Spring MVC, I am using plain Servlets

Comment: Also what I want is the full URL, like protocol://domain/context

Comment: yeah I misunderstood what are you doing.. Never used these before, Good luck

Comment: HttpServletRequest helps you http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my answer. I don't currently see a way to obtain this information except for two ways; capture it on the first request made to the server, or pass it along to the server through configuration files that you can read.

Answer (score 1):

I had done something similar a few years ago.
But there was a little logic involved.

Per

```
request.getRequestURL()
```

you can obtain actually a full path of your application, but if you do this in servlet, your result would be something like this.

```
http://<server:port>/<contextname>/<servletName>
```

What I've done, was just parsing the string, and replacing servletName with empty string.

To make this globally available, i had used the servlets context attributes.

```
getServletContext().setAttribute(key, value)
```

in Servlets you can access them globally via the context object.

in jsp, i had used jstl and accessed this way

```
${applicationScope.key}
```

I think there might be better options to do this, but this had worked for me

Comment: note that this depends on a given request, made by a client, so you cant basically rely on such information..

Answer (score 0):

A web application does not define a host and port for itself, it defines the context root and all of the resources available at the context root. The host and port are part of the server config and not available through any servlet api's other than as part of an inbound request through the request object using such methods as :

```
 HttpServletRequest.getRequestURL()
 ServletRequest.getLocalName()
 ServletRequest.getLocalPort()
```

If you do not want to set up a variable as part of a request the other option is a ServletContextListener - you can set a ServletContext attribute in the contextInitialized method but you will need to read the hostname and port from other means. Requests can get to the attribute using:

```
ServelRequest.getServletContext().geAttribute()
```